# Package name showing as "root" in Jenkin pipeline with cypress junit reporter

Tags: jenkins, npm, junit, jenkins-plugins, cypress

I am using Cypress with JUnit Reporter and the automation suite runs in Jenkin. But in Jenkin's Junit test result the package name always shows root.

How can I change it from root to any other name?

[image]

Below is my  cypress.json reporter option config.

````
"reporter": "cypress-junit",
        "reporterOptions": {
          "testCaseSwitchClassnameAndName": true,
          "rootSuiteTitle":"MYPROJECT-UI",
          "testsuitesTitle": "MYPROJECT-UI-TEST",
          "suiteTitleSeparatedBy": ".",
          "useFullSuiteTitle":true,

          "mochaFile": "cypress/reports/myproject-ui-report[hash].xml",

          "toConsole": false,
          "outputs": true,
          "jenkinsMode":true

          ```
XML File generated post execution of Test Suite:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="MYPROJECT-UI-TEST" time="25.085" tests="2" failures="0">
  <testsuite name="" timestamp="2020-04-28T14:12:06" tests="0" file="cypress\integration\001_Login_spec.js" failures="0" time="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="MYPROJECT-UI.Verify SKLM Login functionlity" timestamp="2020-04-28T14:12:06" tests="2" failures="0" time="25.085">
    <testcase name="Invalid username and password" time="3.707" classname="Login Test">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Valid username and password" time="21.378" classname="Login Test">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
````

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but I think I've just found the answer to that question.

> You can also configure the testsuites.name attribute by setting reporterOptions.testsuitesTitle and **the root suite's name attribute** by setting **reporterOptions.rootSuiteTitle**

https://github.com/michaelleeallen/mocha-junit-reporter

Section: Results Report

Edit:
Example usage in cypress.json file:

```
{
  "reporter": "junit",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "results/my-test-output.xml",
    "toConsole": true
  }
}
```

Did not test it though yet.

Comment: I'm still using 'root' as a default name and as time passes it turned out that it doesn't bother me so much. So the answer will be - probably not but I'm not sure.